# Change data content with a button, (change the sql id according to the button click)

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just try to make simple content change in my html page from mysql with php.

This is my sql I want to use and I have "Next Post" button,
what would be the best way to make the button change the id to 2,3,4,5.. and then on then on.. 
Just cant get this figure out, I don't know what's better to use here Get or how do I do it couldn't find answer

```
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = 1";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please read about SQL injection so that in making this change you do not create a security hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable for id and use a post from your HTML where when you press the button it updates the number in the id variable. I have not tested this but maybe something like this?

```html
<php?
$$servername = **********
$server_username = ***************
$server_password = ****************
$dbName = *****************

$id = 1;

//Make Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $server_username, $server_password, $dbName);
//Check Connection
if(!$conn)
{
    die("Connection Failed". mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT *  FROM `posts` WHERE .$id"

?>
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="<?php $id++ ?>">+</button>
```

etc... just have something in your HTML which will update the 'id' value or do something in the HTML code above that increments the variable and. And you can just place the php code in the same file as the html code without using post or you can alter it to use post if you would like.

Comment: Thats seems like the right solution thank you very much Nathan!

Comment: Should I use post or get? what would be the best

Comment: So, it depends. If you are going to place the code within your html file you will not need to use post or get, but if you place it in a separate file like id.php you can use a post command then add a form around the button with an action="post" and that should get the job done. Just change the id to a post command. That should work if it doesn't let me know and I can take a better look at it!